# MySQL - join two queries the second being filtered by the result from the first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where a rearch will return a single product SKU which I would return like so for example:

```
SELECT 
pr.SKU,
pr.pkSKU,
pr.ColorDescription,
pr.CommonBrandName,
pr.BaseModel
FROM tbl_products AS pr WHERE pr.pkSKU = 160386  
ORDER BY pr.CommonBrandName, pr.SKU, pr.StandardColor
```

But the SKU may have other alternative colours available which are linked via the BaseModel and I need to display these as well which I know I can do by writing a new query like so:

```
SELECT 
pr.SKU,
pr.pkSKU,
pr.ColorDescription,
pr.CommonBrandName,
pr.BaseModel
FROM tbl_products AS pr WHERE pr.BaseModel = "result from previous query"  
ORDER BY pr.CommonBrandName, pr.SKU, pr.StandardColor
```

But what I would really like to do is combine this into one query, is this possible ?

Secondly if it is I would need the results ordered so that the SKU's returned from the 1st query are always listed first like so:

Searched SKU
Alternative Color
Searched SKU
Alternative Color
Alternative Color
Searched SKU
Alternative Color
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could be like this

```
SELECT 
pr.SKU,
pr.pkSKU,
pr.ColorDescription,
pr.CommonBrandName,
pr.BaseModel
FROM tbl_products pr 
   INNER JOIN tbl_products pr1 ON pr.BaseModel = pr1.BaseModel
WHERE pr2.pkSKU = 160386  
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN pr.pkSKU = 160386 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   pr.CommonBrandName, pr.SKU, pr.StandardColor
```

Comment: Modifying your answer like so to cope with 2 or more results:

`SELECT 
pr.SKU,
pr.pkSKU,
pr.ColorDescription,
pr.CommonBrandName,
pr.BaseModel
FROM tbl_products pr 
   INNER JOIN tbl_products pr1 ON pr.BaseModel = pr1.BaseModel
WHERE pr2.pkSKU = ((pr.pkSKU = 160386) OR (pr.pkSKU = 125912))  
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN pr.pkSKU = ((pr.pkSKU = 160386) OR (pr.pkSKU = 125912)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   pr.CommonBrandName, pr.BaseModel, pr.SKU, pr.StandardColor`
   
Is perfect, thank you